# Best way to store a list/array of different subclasses

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a program to simulate a card game. I have class called MagicCard, and a variety of classes that extend card, like card1, card2... I want to find a way to store a list/array of different cards (a deck). Each card1, card2... has a "special" effect that they trigger when they are played, so the need a unique function, which is why i need all the different subclasses. A lot of the cards have a similar properties. How can I store the deck in a reasonable and accessible manner? (I want the deck to easily be manipulated so I can add a card, or remove a card from it when I want).

Currently this is what I have:

```
//My Code
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace mtgDeckSimulator
{

    //General properties of a magic card, extended by individual classes
    class cardProperties
    {
        private String cardName;
        /*Mana Array Aranged in the following Order:
         * [Colorless,White,Blue,Black,Red,Green] */
        private int[] manaCost;
        /* Card Type int definitions:
         * 0-Artifact
         * 1-Creature
         * 2-Enchantment
         * 3-Instant
         * 4-Land
         * 5-Planeswalker
         * 6-Sorcery
         * 7-Tribal */
        private int cardType;
        public int attack;
        public int defense;
        private bool permBool;
        private bool isLegen; //Or is restricted to one copy
        public cardProperties(String cardName,int[] manaCostIn,int cardTypeIn,int attack,int defense,bool permBoolIn,bool isLegenIn)
        {
            this.cardName = cardName;
            manaCost = manaCostIn;
            cardType = cardTypeIn;
            permBool = permBoolIn;
            isLegen = isLegenIn;
        }
        //Get Variables
        public String getCardName()
        {
            return cardName;
        }
        public int[] getManaCost()
        {
            return manaCost;
        }
        public int getCardType()
        {
            return cardType;
        }
        public bool getPermBool()
        {
            return permBool;
        }
        public bool getIsLegen()
        {
            return isLegen;
        }
        //Other Methods
    }

    //Interface for magic cards
    interface MagicCard
    {
        int SpecialEffect();
    }
    #region Magic Card List
    class WallOfOmens : cardProperties, MagicCard
    {
        public WallOfOmens()
            : base("Wall of Omens", new int[6] { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 1, 0, 4, true, false)
        {
            ;
        }
        public int SpecialEfect()
        {
            return 1;
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    class Card2 : cardProperties, MagicCard
    {
        public int SpecialEfect()
        {
            return 2;
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Is there a better way to implement this? Also the code does not work as it tells me WallOfOmens and Card2 do not implement SpecialEffect(), why is that happening?

Comment: If you spell `SpecialEfect` as `SpecialEffect` like in the interface it might work better.

Comment: Because you're not saying that your functions implement the interface. They should be called MagicCard.SpecialEffect()

Comment: @Stu: In C#, you don't need to qualify the interface unless it's ambiguous (i.e, multiple interfaces with the same member)

Comment: @Mike Caron, you don't need to specify it even if you have multiple interfaces with the same member if they have the same implementation. It is only if you want different implementations for the different interfaces you need the explicit implementation, but you should really avoid that if possible.

Comment: @Albin True enough. I guess it really boils down to what's "ambiguous" :)

Comment: @chetjan : In your question, you talk about subclasses, but you don't seem to have any in your example. You do have some class that implement some interfaces though.

Comment: @Mike: gaah... too much VB.NET lately!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would consider an alternative, use composition instead of inheritance. Composition is more flexible than inheritance, it allows you to combine different aspects more freely than inheritance.

Instead of creating

```
abstract class BaseCard{abstract int SpecialEffect();}
class Card1 : BaseCard{override int SpecialEffect(){return 1;}}
class Card2 : BaseCard{override int SpecialEffect(){return 2;}}
...
```

you create different SpecialEffect-classes

```
abstract class SpecialEffectBase{abstract int SpecialEffect();}
class SpecialEffect1 : SpecialEffectBase{override int SpecialEffect(){return 1;}}
class SpecialEffect2 : SpecialEffectBase{override int SpecialEffect(){return 2;}}
...
```

and assemble the different cards in a factory

```
Card card1 = new Card(new SpecialEffect1());
Card card2 = new Card(new SpecialEffect2());
```

This might sound like just another step of indirection, but if you reuse several some effects in different cards, and have other properties that differ between cards, like Rules or something you can assemble them like this

```
Card card1 = new Card(new SpecialEffect1(), new Rule1());
Card card2 = new Card(new SpecialEffect1(), new Rule2());
Card card3 = new Card(new SpecialEffect2(), new Rule1());
Card card4 = new Card(new SpecialEffect2(), new Rule2());
...
```

Another benefit is that it forces you to encapsulate the SpecialEffect-rules in the SpecialEffect-classes, the Rule-rules in the Rule-classes, etc. instead of having them all over the place in your Card class.

Comment: It gives me an error with your code, underlining return and saying "type expected". What am I doing wrong? (sry I'm quite new to coding).

Comment: It seems to work if I replace (return 1;) with {return 1;} so it seems to be working now.

Comment: @chetjan, sorry, I fixed that now

Answer (score 1):

You have misspelt `SpecialEffect` in the classes that implement that interface. Fixing the typo should help.

Once you have the compilation working you can store `MagicCard` instances in any (preferably generic) container.

It might be helpful to extend the `MagicCard` interface so that it has a property that returns the object as `cardProperties`, for easy accessibility.  Dual inheritance makes it more tricky to access both the base class and interface for a container element, since you can only store one Type in the generic container.  It seems a fair bet that any `MagicCard` will have `cardProperties`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a List class. where T is cardProperties or MagicCard
Also, instead of using an interface, why don't you remove the interface MagicCard and add the int SpecialEffect(); as an abstract method to cardProperties:

public abstract int SpecialEffect();

abstract methods must be implemented by subclasses, then u have to mark the cardProperties as abstract too

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look up [Polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Ideally you should store a `List<Card>`. All the different cards inherit from your base class `Card`, and some cards implement an interface called `IMagicCard`.

Alternatively, if there's only one type of `MagicCard`, it could directly inherit from `Card`

So, you could Have:

```
Card
WizardCard : Card, IMagicCard
WitchCard : Card, IMagicCard
HumanCard : Card
```

Or

```
Card
MagicCard : Card
NonMagic: Card
```

I would recommend the former, but depending on how you structure your game, both might be applicable.

You'll have to excuse me if I misunderstood your intent.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would have made `MagicCard` as a parent class, and not as an interface. In it, you can declare `SpecialEffect` as virtual to allow overrides even if it's not required. Then, in your deck class, you can use a `List<MagicCard>` object, just as andrewjs suggested.